# How to remove formatting characters?

Tags: php, jquery

I set formatting mask on a textfield :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#budget_para_prevision").inputmask("9999999999999.99"); // 13 digits before "." 
});
```

The problem happens after posting the form when the length of the digits before the "." sign is less than 13 then the formatting characters are written automatically with the `$_POST` variable , it gives something like this :
391000000000_.__

So how to remove the `_` and the `.` sign in this case ?

Comment: [Replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) `_` with empty character, then [trim](http://php.net/RTRIM) the `.` from the end

Comment: not sure how it is coming from, but I personally would workaround that by getting only the number digits from it.

Comment: Isn't there a regular expression to fix it ?

Comment: `[0-9]+`? @pheromix . As long as the output will always be similar to that a regex will work properly, but trimming and replacing is way faster here, to be honest.

Comment: @pheromix: Don't use regex when you don't need to. People always seem to overuse regex, it's not efficient. Just replace and trim

Comment: @briosheje: No, because that wouldn't work with decimal numbers if they were entered

Comment: @mousefan: well, maybe a preg_match_all with that regex can work? it will still get it, I'm not getting why it shouldn't work, but I totally agree that it's not needed, since trim and replace are way enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the unwanted characters using a combination of `str_replace` and `rtrim`. Something like this:

```
$input = "391000000000_.__";
$result = str_replace("_", "", $input); // Remove instances of underscore.
$result = rtrim($result, "."); // Remove the dot if it's the last character.
```

Or you can just do the whole lot with a single `rtrim`:

```
$result = rtrim($input, "._");
```

Comment: All you really need here is `rtrim($input, "._")`. But fixing the input would be better.

Comment: @jeroen: Ah yeah, that would be better!

Answer (score 2):

> You can have part of your mask be optional. Anything listed after '?'
>   within the mask is considered optional user input. The common example
>   for this is phone number + optional extension.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //if 12 and more digits are optional
    $("#budget_para_prevision").inputmask("999999999999?9.99"); 
});
```

From [docs](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: What inputmask plugin are you referring to exactly?

Comment: jquery.inputmask.min.js

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would depend on what jQuery inputmask plugin you are using exactly, but if it is [Robin Herbots](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) plugin, you can make parts of your input optional and specify lengths:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#budget_para_prevision").inputmask("9{1,13}[.99]"); // 13 digits before "." 
});
```

Of course you could also fix it at the backend with `rtrim($input, "._")` but preventing the input in the first place would be better.

Comment: jquery.inputmask.min.js